# Unknowns in Circle Equation

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, circles

The circle $x^2-y^2 + ax -2y -15 = 0$ contains the point  $P(-6, 5)$. How would I find a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You let $x=-6$ and $y=5$ in your equation for the circle.  Then solve for $a$.